# """CommandException: No URLs matched. Do the files you're operating on exist? """ error while running gsutil -m rm -r -I command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I have many folders stored in gcs bucket and i want to delete those folders recursively.

```
gsutil -m ls -d gs://bucket_name/folder_1/*/ | grep 2021-03-17 | gsutil -m rm -r
```

So basically i want to delete all the folders recursively whose names contain "2021-03-17" string.

Getting below error when running it:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched. Do the files you're operating on exist?
```

I Can't delete each file seperately and my usecase is to delete the folder itself recursively.

How can i solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Use xargs to execute `gsutil rm -r` line per line from the output of grep.

```
gsutil ls -d gs://bucket_name/folder_1/* | grep 2021-03-17 | xargs gsutil -m rm -r
```

Test:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you'll probably want to write a small wrapper script for. The pipeline you currently have doesn't account for the command output from command #1 being empty. Also, `gsutil rm` doesn't accept items from stdin unless you use the `-I` flag (you could also use xargs to substitute the arguments in). I'd say it's worth writing a short wrapper script that does these things:

- Run the gsutil ls command to fetch the directories (it's possible none exist, which is probably why you're seeing that message).
- For each directory, see if it matches the regex.
- Supply the matching paths to `gsutil -m rm` as arguments. If there are more than ~32k matches (the max number of arguments for a command), you'll need to do them in batches.